# How to add SVG from Fontawesome react code snippet in React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-icons, react-font-awesome

I am using CSS module. Does it affect in how to add the Font awesome icon?
I already installed all the required dependencies.

nav.js

```
import React from "react";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

import classes from "./Nav.module.css";

import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";

const Nav = (props) => {
  return (
    <section className={classes.nav}>
      <h1>ReactMeals</h1>
      <Button className={classes["nav--btn"]}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fa-solid", "fa-cart-shopping"]} />
        Your Cart
        <span className={classes["num__items"]}>0</span>
      </Button>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "foodorderapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried to through Font awesome documentation. But it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try this <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping" />

Comment: Yes, I did. IDE does not throw any error. but the icon does not even show up

Comment: follow these steps https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons

Comment: try to use different icon maybe you are writing wrong con name
try  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee"/>